# Disjoint Set in a special ways?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, disjoint-sets

We implement Disjoint Data structure with tree. in this data structure `makeset()` create a set with one element, `merge(i, j)` merge two tree of set `i` and `j` in such a way that tree with lower height become a child of root of the second tree. if we do `n` `makeset()` operation and `n-1 merge()` operations in random manner, and then do one find operation. what is the cost of this find operation in worst case?

```
I) O(n)
II) O(1)
III) O(n log n)
IV) O(log n)
```

Answer: IV.

> Anyone could mentioned a good tips that the author get this solution?

Comment: Can you provide the source of this claim?

Comment: there is a typo, I correct it. it's a local exam, and has scanned document. @amit

Comment: I think the answer is aaaa

Comment: One of us is missing something, because the trees implementation of disjoint data set is O(logn) worst case find.

Comment: @amit you are right. I translate it with typo. is it okey? the answer is logn

Comment: how you get this value ? @amit is it possible learn me?

Answer (score 1):

The O(log n) find is only true when you use *union by rank* (also known as *weighted union*). When we use this optimisation, we always place the tree with lower rank under the root of the tree with higher rank. If both have the same rank, we choose arbitrarily, but increase the rank of the resulting tree by one. This gives an O(log n) bound on the depth of the tree. We can prove this by showing that a node that is *i* levels below the root (equivalent to being in a tree of rank >= *i*) is in a tree of at least 2<sup>*i*</sup> nodes (this is the same as showing a tree of size *n* has log *n* depth). This is easily done with induction.

```
Induction hypothesis: tree size is >= 2^j for j < i.
Case i == 0: the node is the root, size is 1 = 2^0.
Case i + 1: the length of a path is i + 1 if it was i and the tree was then placed underneath
            another tree. By the induction hypothesis, it was in a tree of size >= 2^i at
            that time. It is being placed under another tree, which by our merge rules means
            it has at least rank i as well, and therefore also had >= 2^i nodes. The new tree
            therefor has >= 2^i + 2^i = 2^(i + 1) nodes.
```

Comment: there is a nice solution +1 but I think there is a typo here

Comment: Sorry this problem not says union by rank, says thing differnet. isnt it?

Comment: @MaryamKoj: you say that when merging you put the tree with lower height below the tree with higher height. This is exactly what is known as _union by rank_ (the _rank_ is always the deepest level of any leaf).

Comment: @user3661613 care to say where the typo is?

Comment: sorry. maybe my misunderstanding. would you please check your proof part?

Comment: @user3661613 I don't see any problems... can you be more specific?